# Struggling with a recursive expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, recursion

So I was looking into recursive expressions and recently dealt with this expression:

$$ f(i) = q \times (f(i-1)+1) + \bar{q} \times f(i-1) $$

where $q$ is a probability between $0$ and $1$ and $\bar{q} = 1-q$.

A non-recursive formula is quite simple ($ = q \times i$)

But when I change the recursive expression to:

$$ f(i) = q \times (f(i-1)+1) + \frac{\bar{q} \times f(i-1)}{2} $$

the solution I found becomes:

$$ \frac{q-q\times(q+\frac{\bar{q}}{2})}{1-(q+\frac{\bar{q}}{2})} $$

There might be other solutions though.
I do find it strange that a relative small change in the recursive expression leads to a significantly more complex non-recursive formula.

I now got another recursive expression:

$$ f(i) = q \times i + \bar{q} \times f(i-1) $$

The solution to this one (again, there are other ones) is:

$$ i-\frac{\bar{q}\times(1-\bar{q}^i)}{q} $$

But now when I do the same 'thing' as with the other expression:

$$ f(i) = q \times i + \frac{\bar{q} \times f(i-1)}{2} $$

I get completely stuck in finding a solution (i.e. a non-recursive formula).

Does anyone have an idea to solve this recursion or any hints?

Comment: All your recursions seem to be of the form $a_{n+1}=\alpha a_n +\beta n +\gamma$ which can easily be dealt with by using generating functions.

Comment: Can you show us how you got $f(i) = qi$ for the first one?

Comment: $f(i) = q \bigr[ \sum_{j=1}^i j (\frac{1-q}{2})^{i-j} \bigr] + (\frac{1-q}{2})^{i-1}(1-q)$. You can get rid of the sigma using calculus if you want, but in any case this is a non-recursive formula.

Comment: @ancientmathematician you got any good resources? For those specific form of recursive expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am unfamiliar with generating functions, I am forced to ignore the comment of ancientmathematician, and proceed very inelegantly.

> $$ f(i) = q \times i + \frac{\bar{q} \times f(i-1)}{2} $$

> I get completely stuck in finding a solution (i.e. a non-recursive formula).

Assume that $f(0) = 0$ and let $r = \frac{1-q}{2}.$

Then:
$f(1) = q.$ 
$f(2) = 2q + rq.$ 
$f(3) = 3q + r(2q + rq) = 3q + 2rq + r^2q.$

Inductively assume that

$$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n qkr^{(n-k)}.$$

Then

$$f(n+1) ~=~ (n+1)q + \sum_{k=1}^n qkr^{([n+1] - k)}
~=~ \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} qkr^{([n+1]-k)}.$$